# Is there a reason for why there are no shell apps for modern ui?

Tags: windows, windows-8, modern-ui

As a Win 8 / .net developer, I would like to have a fullscreen shell app for the Modern UI interface. Now, I couldn't find a shell app in the Windows Store...

My question is - is it even possible to create a shell with full access to the file system, processes etc. in the sandboxed Modern UI environment?

Comment: You don't see the contradictions in your question, where you want "full access to ..." in a *sandboxed* environment?

Comment: Yep, I do.. My question was more about whether or not you could work around the limitations in the Modern UI environment.

Comment: If we could work around the limitations, so could far more malicious code - and so the sandbox wouldn't be effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fire up the "Ancient" desktop and the Command Prompt and Power Shell are still there.

If you really wanted to I suppose you could create a "Modern" app which invoked old style DOS and PowerShell commands in the background. But the sort of user who would be interested in raw shell commands would go straight to the Old Style desktop anyway.

Comment: I understand you still have the "ancient" implementation, but I would like to migrate as much as possible of my workflow to the modern UI environment. Perhaps my preferences are a bit... special ;-)

Comment: Strange -- most experienced users automatically use the "Ancient" interface (after bringing back the Start button from the dead!). The "modern" interface is next to useless. Consider the only way to shutdown the mail app is CNTRL-ALT-DEL and kill it with task manager. Its not so much user unfriendly as designed for imaginary users from another planet with no history of using a computer.

Comment: I get you're not a huge fan of the new UI, but I think you're giving it a worse rep than it deserves. Again, I think the UI would do better with at least the same access to the OS as the desktop apps, so that you could actually make what you'd want.

PS - I promise I'm not from another planet, nor imaginary. I also have a few years of experience with using computers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible by combining a modern UI app (presenting an interface) with a desktop application (doing the work); I'm not sure to what extent apps are protected from applications.  But to pass Windows Store validation the modern UI app would have to do something useful in the absence of the desktop application ... you might get away with embedding this functionality into a larger app, but I think you'd be at least bending the rules.

Comment: Yeah, that's the hunch I got too. Too bad, really. Although I understand the benefits of sandboxing, it really takes away possibilities of new work flow patterns and at least a few ideas.

Comment: Of course, an app that presents a console interface for *another* machine wouldn't be breaking the rules. :-)